# Java Not Converting String to Long Object Properly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, websphere, aix

We're using Spring/Hibernate on a Websphere Application Server for AIX.  On my Windows machine, the problem doesn't occur--only when running off AIX.  When a user logs in with an account number, if they prefix the '0' to their login ID, the application rejects the login.  In the DB2 table, the column is of numeric type, and there shouldn't be a problem converting '090....' to '90...'

Anyone else experience a problem like this?  Both machines have Java v1.5.

To be more specific, the flow is FormView -> LoginValidator -> LoginController

In LoginValidator, the value of login is null with the prefixed 0.  Without the 0, the value is what it should be (But again, this is only on the AIX environment--on 2 Windows environments it's fine).  Here's the snippet of code where the object equals null..

```
public class LoginValidator implements Validator  {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return Login.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        System.out.println("Inside LoginValidator");
        Login login = (Login) obj;
        //null value
        System.out.println("Before conversion in Validator, store id = " 
              + login.getStoreId()); 
    }
}
```

I've also written this short Java program for constructing a Long from a String, and using the java binary that is packaged with WebSphere

```
public class String2Long {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "09012179";
        String b = "9012179";

        Long _a = new Long(a);
        Long _b = new Long(b);

        System.out.println(a + " => " + _a); //09012179 => 9012179
        System.out.println(b + " => " + _b); //9012179 => 9012179
        System.out.println("_a.equals(_b) " + _a.equals(_b)); //_a.equals(_b) true
    }
}
```

## SOLUTION

Comment: Could it be that the code converting to a Long sees the initial 0 and thinks it's octal?

Comment: It's possible, but is that platform dependent? Wouldn't that problem also occur on a Windows machine?

Comment: That certainly shouldn't be the problem. But try to isolate the failing code and then reproduce it on its own - a short console app is good for this (or a unit test, of course).

Comment: Oh, and showing the code that actually does the conversion from String to Long would be rather handy.

Comment: Well, you can test this by doing a manual conversion to a long with Long.parseLong() and see what it returns... or manually do a Long.parseLong(login, 10) to make sure it's in decimal.  (Where login is the variable you're converting)

Comment: I know there is platform dependency in the underlying C libraries (strtol?).  If the JVMs use the C libraries directly, it's possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if its even coming in as a String.  It's an implicit conversion of the fields values (username, password) to the Login POJO, where username is of type Long.

Comment: Then isolate that implicit conversion, work out exactly how it's happening, and test that. Just trace the data flow. It sounds like it's coming from a form, so it's definitely a string there. Work out how it gets to the Login POJO.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any classpath differences on the AIX and windows machine? I think it has less to do with different platforms that it does different instances of your app server. Are you SURE the applicationContext is identical? Also, are you using Struts validation anywhere?

Comment: What does your program print out on AIX then?

Comment: @matt b: We are using Spring validation.  It is bypassing binding the Command object to the POJO and there it's outputting null in the Validation class.  It is Java 5 on both machines, and WAS 6.1.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: What's in the comments adjacent to the System.Outs is the output on AIX

Comment: Okay, so have you debugged into it (on Windows) and seen where the POJO is meant to have the property set, and by what?

Comment: What would you suggest I do for debugging?  Can I just startup the Application Server in debug mode?

Comment: Yup. Put a breakpoint in the property setter (I assume it's a property) and look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SOLUTION

A co-worker did some research on Spring updates, and apparently this error was correct in v. 2.5.3:

> CustomNumberEditor treats number with leading zeros as decimal (removed unwanted octal support while preserving hex)

We were using Spring 2.0.5.  We simply replaced the jars with Spring 2.5.4, and it worked as it should have!

Thanks to everyone for your help/assistance.  We will make use of Unit tests in the future, but this just turned out to be a Spring bug.

Answer (score 3):

Well there's an awful lot of things going on there. You really need to try to isolate the problem - work out what's being sent to the database, what's being seen by Java etc.

Try to pin it down in a short but complete program which *just* shows the problem - then you'll be in a much stronger position to file a bug or fix your code.

Comment: It has to be something when Spring is constructing the Command object, since that's the first thing it does before going to the Validator.  I'll do a SystemOut inside the setters and see what's going on there, thanks.

Comment: Rather than using System.out, I suggest you use a debugger. Even if you can't use it on the AIX box, you should be able to see what's doing the conversion on your dev box - which should let you isolate the faulty code.

Answer (score 2):

Trace through the program following the path of the String all the way to database and make unit tests for every single method on that path. And don't just take the shortest possible route here, make multiple unit tests with different inputs and expected outputs to really see what went possibly wrong. Assuming you don't find any errors, run the same unit tests on the other computer and you should be able to pinpoint the bug. From the top of my head I'd assume it may have something to do with case sensitivity but there really is no way to be sure.

Next time, use TDD.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Java, but this might happen the string is interpreted as octal string because of the leading "0".

You can probably work around this using Long.parseLong(a, 10).

Comment: A string value should not go through any octal interpretation.  But Java doesn't do that anyways.

new Long(a) calls Long.parseLong(a, 10) if you look at the JDK code

Comment: I did not look at the JDK code, but I noticed the standard saying something like that. I just thought that perhaps IBM might have a different implementation which contains a bug.
Explicitly calling Long.parseLong(a, 10) would test this hypothesis.